# Scala immutable Map vs List of tuples

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, tuples

What's the difference between an immutable Map and a List of tuples in Scala? When should I use each of them? Which one is preferable if both are possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two data structures are quite different.

1.`Map` look up time is `O(1)`. In a list it would be `O(n)`

Therefore, if you need to look up elements in you key -> value mapping use `map`.

```
scala> val myMap = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)

scala> myMap.get("a")
res7: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> myMap.getOrElse("a", 0)
res8: Int = 1

scala> myMap("a")
res9: Int = 1
```

As others have pointed out: Two other major differences are:

2.Keys in `Map` must be unique

```
scala> val myList = List(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3))
myList: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2), (a,3))

scala> myList.toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, b -> 2)
```

3.`Map` is un-ordered

```
scala> Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5).toList
res2: List[(String, Int)] = List((e,5), (a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4))
```

Comment: There is very important difference you did not mention: `Map` keys need to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't agree (with @Akavall) that the two data structures are quite different. They both represent a sequence (or *List* in this case) of key-value pairs. In that sense they are entirely homologous. They do have different **behaviors**, such as the lookup performance that @Akavall mentions. However, that performance is only true for a *Map* that is implemented as a *HashMap* (or something similar). That aspect of behavior is not defined by *Map* itself. There is one other difference with *Maps*, however. It is customary for the key values in a *Map* to be distinct (see the definition in [Associative Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)).

I would suggest that each has its uses. *Map[K,V]* is best if you are reasonably sure that the keys will be unique and want fast lookup times. *Seq[(K,V)]* is best where you have no requirement to do fast lookups (or perhaps you know that you might want to do the lookup in either direction, i.e. from *K->V* or from *V->K*) or when you expect that keys might be duplicated. Frequently in Scala, a *Map* is constructed from a sequence of tuples.

Comment: "They both represent a sequence of key-value pairs." – No, a `Map` is *not* a sequence (and it doesn't extend `Seq` either). `Map`s are un-ordered. That is the dominant difference between a map and an association list.

Comment: The word "sequence" was badly chosen -- I needed a word that meant collection but without any overtones. I didn't mean to imply an ordering and  I certainly didn't intend _Seq_, else I'd have said so.